# Why is Object.__proto__.__proto__ not null?

Tags: javascript, prototype

My understanding is that the `Object.__proto__` is the 'top-level' prototype object in javascript.  I would expect its `__proto__` to be null, but in Google Chrome (haven't tried other browsers), it isn't.  Why is that?

## Edit

I know the following image is probably a re-hash of the one below, but I made it myself to check my understanding.  Is there anything wrong with it?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Object` is a function, it's `__proto__` is an empty function `function() {}`. The root object is an empty object `{}`, not `Object`. So, when you have an object like `{foo:1, bar:1}` its relationships look like this:

[image]

Comment: I mostly understand that diagram, but I'm a little confused as to why there is two entities named "function/Function" and "object/Object".  Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Nevermind, I think i got it.  The top left entity represents the Function object, and the one right beside it represents an instance created using Function, right?

Comment: This image was extremely helpful, and sparked more inquiry.  Thank you.

Comment: @jrahhali: you're right, I uploaded a better diagram.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're mistaking `Object.__proto__` for `Object.prototype`.

`Object.prototype.__proto__` is indeed null, because `Object` doesn't extend anything.

`Object` itself, however, is a function - aka. an instance of `Function`.
Since `Function` extends `Object`, it's prototype has a `__proto__` property.
You can thus take a detour over `Object.__proto__.__proto__` to reach `Object.prototype`, in fact:

```
Object.prototype === Object.__proto__.__proto__ // should yield true
```

Comment: Yes, i was confusing Object.__proto__ with Object.prototype.  Talk about a confusing relationship.  Thanks.  I wish I could accept two answers.